# vue drag and drag custom components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuedraggable

I'm trying to make custom components draggable with vuedraggable package but for some reason i can't make it work, i also want it to work by copying not moving the component altogether

here's my code:

```
<template>
<div id="main" class="main w-1/4 h-full bg-gray-900">
    <draggable v-model="comps" v-bind="dragOptions" item-key="id">
        <template #item="{ element }">
            <li>
                <component
                    :is="element">
                </component>
            </li>
        </template>
    </draggable>
</div>
```

script:

```
data() {
return {
  comps: [
    "NavBarOne",
  ],
  dragOptions: {
    animation: 300,
  },
};
methods: {
handleDrop(event: { preventDefault: () => void; dataTransfer: { getData: (arg0: string) => string; }; }) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Get the copied item data from the event dataTransfer
  const itemData = JSON.parse(event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));

  // Create a copy of the item
  const newItem = { ...itemData, id: `item-${Date.now()}` };

  // Add the copied item to your items array
  this.comps.push(newItem);
},
```

I get this error in the console:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'header')
    at getSlot (vuedraggable.js:59:24)
    at computeChildrenAndOffsets (vuedraggable.js:65:18)
    at Proxy.render (vuedraggable.js:166:54)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:816:16)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5701:46)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:178:19)
    at instance.update (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5814:51)
    at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5822:5)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5612:5)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5565:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I used `npm install vuedraggable` to install the vuedraggable package. As I understand it now, is that this is only for Vue 2.

I uninstalled and used `npm install vuedraggable@next` instead, which is for Vue 3 and my issue was resolved. I hope this helps.